# How to load .gds file into Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, gdscript

I have a `.gds` file. How can I read that file with `pandas` and do some analysis? What is the best way to do that in Python? The file can be downloaded [here](https://gofile.io/d/rb2CMx).

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the encoding and read the data using `latin1`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('example.gds',header=27,encoding='latin1')
```

will get you the data file, also you need to skip the first 27 rows of data for the real pandas meat of the file.

Comment: thank you so much but still does not work. First time I tried .it was working perfectly,but still does not work

Comment: What went wrong?  Could I have some more information?

Comment: Thank you very much.I Have uploaded a new file.This is the link:       https://gofile.io/d/54Ll76

Answer (score 0):

The `gdspy` package comes handy for such applications. For example:

```py
import numpy
import gdspy

gdsii = gdspy.GdsLibrary(infile="filename.gds")
main_cell = gdsii.top_level()[0]  # Assume a single top level cell
points = main_cell.polygons[0].polygons[0]
for p in points:
    print("Points: {}".format(p))
```